# Add comment character # in many lines at once Python

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

I am wondering, if its possible comment many lines at once in Python Jupyter Notebook or/and Spyder.

What I mean is to change this:

```
x=2
y=3
z=4
x=3
y=4
z=5
```

Into this

```
#x=2
#y=3
#z=4
x=3
y=4
z=5
```

Is it possible? It would speed up my work many times :)

Comment: This depends on your text editor, not Python. It  is possible with many text editors

Comment: I meant Jupyter notebook or Spyder :) Do you know how to do it there?

Comment: I've duplicated this to an existing question on how to do this in Spyder. For Jupyter, see [How do I comment out multiple lines in Jupyter Ipython notebook?](//stackoverflow.com/q/29885371)

Comment: Thanks, I probably should train my searching skills .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure that I understood correctly, but this available per editor.

For example, in each editor you'll have a shortcut for commenting out/in lines at once, so it depends on the editor.

In Jupyter for example, you can use `Ctrl` + `/` which works for me.

As if you're writing just in a simple notepad, I can however suggest the following three single-quotes at the start and at the end.

For example:

```
'''x=2
y=3
z=4
x=3'''
y=4
z=5
```

So the part from `x=2` to the part of `x=3` is currently commented out from the code and won't be executed.